# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. (Android.banker.A2af7 trojen detected)

Tags: java, android

Android studio showing this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\M\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes_b11ac8137589884ed512c93c59b969dc5dc99df3.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Every time i run the app, quick heal shows Android.banker.A2af7(PUP) tojen is detected and it quarantines the file.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I have no idea what is happening.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Try to **rebuild** and **clean** project.

Answer (score 0):

I was also a QuickHeal User Some Files Created By Android Studio Are Considered As Virus By quickheal an easy fix can be to ignore the directory of your project in quikheal scans.. 
Hope This Helps..